# How to automatically play video when focus reaches video/

Tags: css, html, video, scroll

In my web page i have 5 video in a single page. I want video play when i see that section.

**For example**

After the page loading video one auto play if i scroll my page to second section second video need to play

I used video tag in my code.

```
<video id="jp_video_4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="Workspace/assets/videos/Play and Learn SLOW.webm"></video>
```

Any one know how to slove this

Answer (score 5):

You will have to get all the position of your video elements, relative to the page, and compare it at each scroll event with the <s>`window.scrollY`</s> `pageYOffset` property.

Here is an annotated snippet where I used [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method to get the video elements positions.

```js
// the list of our video elements
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
// an array to store the top and bottom of each of our elements
var videoPos = [];
// a counter to check our elements position when videos are loaded
var loaded = 0;

// Here we get the position of every element and store it in an array
function checkPos() {
  // loop through all our videos
  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var element = videos[i];
    // get its bounding rect
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    // we may already have scrolled in the page 
    // so add the current pageYOffset position too
    var top = rect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    var bottom = rect.bottom + window.pageYOffset;
    // it's not the first call, don't create useless objects
    if (videoPos[i]) {
      videoPos[i].el = element;
      videoPos[i].top = top;
      videoPos[i].bottom = bottom;
    } else {
      // first time, add an event listener to our element
      element.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
          if (++loaded === videos.length - 1) {
            // all our video have ben loaded, recheck the positions
            // using rAF here just to make sure elements are rendered on the page
            requestAnimationFrame(checkPos)
          }
        })
        // push the object in our array
      videoPos.push({
        el: element,
        top: top,
        bottom: bottom
      });
    }
  }
};
// an initial check
checkPos();


var scrollHandler = function() {
  // our current scroll position

  // the top of our page
  var min = window.pageYOffset;
  // the bottom of our page
  var max = min + window.innerHeight;

  videoPos.forEach(function(vidObj) {
    // the top of our video is visible
    if (vidObj.top >= min && vidObj.top < max) {
      // play the video
      vidObj.el.play();
    }

    // the bottom of the video is above the top of our page
    // or the top of the video is below the bottom of our page
    // ( === not visible anyhow )  
    if (vidObj.bottom <= min || vidObj.top >= max) {
      // stop the video
      vidObj.el.pause();
    }

  });
};
// add the scrollHandler
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, true);
// don't forget to update the positions again if we do resize the page
window.addEventListener('resize', checkPos);
```

```css
video {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
scroll to see and autoplay videos

<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
```

Comment: It's way easier now with the intersection observer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: @AbdallaArbab that's a very good point. Do you want to post your own answer with IntersectionObservers? I could update mine, but having both may not hurt.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Abdalla I tried intersection observer and it really worked.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API explains it really well and I was able to write a simple query (still needs fine tuning) following the documentation which works really well and plays video only when it is visible 100% on screen or pause it.

I also have tried couple of other legacy solutions but they always had some lag if there were 10+ videos on page but intersection observer really worked very smoothly.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let options = {
            root: null,    // browser viewport
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: 1.0 // target element visible 100%
        }

        let observer = new IntersectionObserver(playOnFocus, options);
        let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.video-fluid');
        targets.forEach(target => {    // adding observer for all videos
            observer.observe(target);
        });
    });

    const playOnFocus = (entries, observer) => {    // callback
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if(entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.play();    // play target video
            } else {
                entry.target.pause();    // pause video
            }
        });
    };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works excellently!