# Canvas: Detect if it is visible in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a list of charts. I use [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create those charts. Since my list can have 1 to 100 or more entries initializing all charts at once would not be smart because that would make the ui freeze for a long time. So instead I thought it would be much better to only initialize those charts which are visible inside the view bounds of the browser so that for example only the first chart is getting initialized and when the user scrolls down and the second canvas becomes visible the second is getting initialized and so on.

I have everything setup but the only problem that I have right now is: how can I create an eventlistener or anything similiar which I can add to each canvas element that gets triggered when a canvas becomes visible inside the view bounds of the browser so that i can perform the chart initialization for that canvas?

Comment: [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) might help. ([polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intersection-observer))

Comment: you could store you non initialized charts in an array, then add a scroll event in your page and check if one of those non initialized charts is visible. This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012192/3702797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of OnScreen, a small library that can call a callback function when a `HTMLElement` enters the viewport or the boundaries of its container.

```
// Uses ES6 syntax
import OnScreen from 'onscreen';

const os = new OnScreen();

os.on('enter', 'canvas', (element) => {
    if (!element.chartInitialized) {
        // Initialize the chart

        // Update the `chartInitialized` property
        // to avoid initializing it over and over
        element.chartInitialized = true;
    }
});
```

For more information, take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen/blob/master/README.md#documentation). Don't forget to check the [demos repo](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen-demo) for a couple simple examples.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a solution that is based the JavaScript standard library, without adding dependencies such as jQuery or OnScreen.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [onScreen](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen) jQuery plugin.

It is very easy. You just have to call for each canvas this:

```
$('elements').onScreen({
   container: window,
   direction: 'vertical',
   doIn: function() {
     // initialize canvas
   },
   doOut: function() {
     // Do something to the matched elements as they get off scren
   },
   tolerance: 0,
   throttle: 50,
   toggleClass: 'onScreen',
   lazyAttr: null,
   lazyPlaceholder: 'someImage.jpg',
   debug: false
});
```

Comment: @Mulgard See [dist folder is missing](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen/issues/33): "*the dist/ directory holds compiled code which, in theory, has no place in the repository. This compiled code is available through NPM and you can get it running npm install onscreen in a terminal window.*"

Comment: I'm the author of OnScreen. I've moved away from jQuery and now OnScreen has no dependencies and the API has changed. You can head over to the [demos repo](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen-demo) for a couple examples. You could also take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/silvestreh/onScreen/blob/master/README.md#documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I usually draw some stuff; canvas is an example. Clean **JS**.Here, you can read a lot more about how it works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
canvases.forEach( (canvas) => {
var options = {
      threshold: 0.01,
    };
var canvas_observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  // Loop through the entries
  for (const entry of entries) {
    // Check if the entry is intersecting the viewport
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log("Intersected")
    }
    else{
            console.log("Exit")
    }
  }
}, options);
canvas_observer.observe(canvas);})
```