# OnBecomeVisible for Canvas UI Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was searching for method similar to OnBecameVisible for Canvas UI.
[MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html)

So that I can load and unload image resources based on requirements. But I can't able to find anything useful in this.
I have this kind of page exist which contains 250+ flowers information so I have to manage my texture resources for this.

[image]

If I disable Image component then page loaded correctly in game otherwise game get crashed in iPhone device when I load this page because of too much graphics memory requirements.

So for managing resources loading and unloading, I need some way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canvas: Detect if it is visible in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848126/canvas-detect-if-it-is-visible-in-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution provided by Unity at the moment. But since the visible area is rectangular and related to screen space, you can easily check if your element contained in it.

Here is some post from forums about a helper script and its usage about this situation which should be able to solve your problem:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/test-if-ui-element-is-visible-on-screen.276549/#post-2978773

Comment: Can you please properly write your answer? so I can make this answer as correct because this worked for me correctly and 250+ textures managed easily.

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem :) but I didn't get what makes the answer unproper? I believe it's already very clearly states there is no out of the box solution and links to a custom solution. I shouldn't copy forum content to here if you mean that by proper. Is there anything that you think I should explain more besides that?

Comment: Okay I got your point into this so let me make this correct so that other persons can use this too. Because many places developers were finding for this kind of solution.

Comment: After this step, I stuck at another point within same implementation. Pretty lower frame rate. Can you able to help me into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671113/improve-frame-rate-on-too-many-ui-textures-unity-ui